# Where are C header files in gcc 7?

Tags: linux, gcc

On a linux server which has an old version of gcc (4.4.7), I built gcc 7.4.0 from source code and installed it in a directory within the home.

Now I'm not sure how to use it. The directory includes some subdirectories, one named "include". Inside it there is a folder named "c++". It includes another folder named "7.4.0". But where are C header files? Did the installer install them in a different place? Which address should I provide with `-I` option when compiling a C program?

Unfortunately I don't have the gcc source directory anymore.

Comment: Check `/usr/local/include` or heaven forbid you overwrote `/usr/include`...

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin, shouldn't `make install` install them in the directory specified with the `prefix` option?

Comment: Most C header files are not a part of gcc but a part of your platform C library (normally glibc). You should *not* normally use any `-I` arguments if you installed gcc correctly.

Comment: I would think so, but I've never attempted to build gcc and put it under home. Do you still have the `Makefile` you ran `make install` with? And good point @n.'pronouns'm.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin, No. Unfortunately I deleted the source directory.

Comment: @n.'pronouns'm. you mean gcc doesn't include them? Is there a separate package for them that I can install on my home directory?

Comment: You don't normally need to install a new version of the C library. The version your platform provides is perfectly adequate, gcc itsef is using it. You can install glibc if you want but it can be tricky.

Comment: Yes, that's what he is saying and I should have snapped to it. `glibc` is the second part that packages the headers and the libraries. Note that some distros break it up into multiple packages. You will want a version compatible with gcc 7.4. I guess you will just have to check if there are any version incompatibilities. (and note your distro was compiled against a specific glibc version -- mixing can cause issues)

Comment: @n.'pronouns'm., Many thanks. Maybe a newer glibc is more optimized and includes newer standards of C language.

Comment: I would do that if I knew there is a specific thing from the newer standard I am going to need, otherwise it's too much trouble.

Answer (score 4):

> But where are C header files?

You can find out where gcc expects them by

`echo '#include <stdio.h>' | gcc -xc - -H -v -fsyntax-only`

The `-v` part will print the search paths like

```java
#include "..." search starts here:
#include <...> search starts here:
 /home/...
 /usr/local/include
 ...
```

The `-H` part will print which header files art actually being used:

```
. /usr/include/stdio.h
.. /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/bits/libc-header-start.h
... /usr/include/features.h
etc.
```

The command line with `echo` above can be used if you have no source file handy.  In the case you are interested how, say, `module.c` behaves, you can use `-v` and `-H` when compiling that module, e.g.

`gcc module.c -H -v -o module.elf`

> Which address should I provide with `-I` option when compiling a C program?

Paths where headers of your C project are located if they are not in the current directory.  For simple projects you do not need `-I`: Compiling `module.c` will find `#include "module.h"` if both files are located in the same directory.

The right option to specify extra system header path would be `-isystem`, however **an installation is supposed to find the system headers without any further hacking**, i.e. the supposed search paths must be listed under `#include <...> search starts here:` and without setting `-isystem`.

> Did the installer install them in a different place?

libc implementations (like glibc or Newlib) are not part of GCC whereas the C++ library libstdc++-v3 is hosted with GCC and is built when GCC is configured with `--enable-languages=c++`. The location of the C-libraries and C-headers should be worked out by configure.

For some C-libraries like Newlib, GCC supports in-tree builds so that these target libraries will be contained in the installation and the paths are set appropriately. Building glibc however is much more complicated.